# How to remove white padding block from bottom of android webview app?

Tags: android, html, css, webview

Im pretty new to android coding and I just created a webview app for my church. The apk was generated successfully but I still keep getting this annoying white space at the bottom of the screen.

To date I have removed all the android:padding references in the content_main.xml file but still am having no success.

Ive also searched on here to see if anyone else had the same issue but those threads only helped me get rid of the padding code and not this annoying white space at the bottom.

If you need me to post any code please let me know. Thanks in advance! 
[Here is a picture of what I am talking about with the white block at bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Budna.png)

activity_main.xml------------------

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

activity_main.xml------------------

content_main.xml-------------------

```
<ProgressBar
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/LoadingText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:text="Loading, Please Wait.."
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">
</TextView>

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

content_main.xml------------------

MainActivity.java------------------
package org.communionchapelefca.ccsatx;

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.KeyEvent;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.webkit.WebSettings;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
    import android.widget.ProgressBar;
```

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
private WebView mWebView;
ProgressBar progressBar;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://communionchapelefca.org/edy-home");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());


}

private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{


    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url)
    {
        webView.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        progressBar.setVisibility(view.GONE);
    }

}


@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{ //if back key is pressed
    if((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)&& mWebView.canGoBack())
    {
        mWebView.goBack();
        return true;

    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            MainActivity.this);

    // set title
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Exit");

    // set dialog message
    alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Do you really want to exit?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, close
                    // current activity
                    MainActivity.this.finish();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, just close
                    // the dialog box and do nothing
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    // create alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    // show it
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

}
MainActivity.java------------------

For the html code for the page we use Wordpress to host it. I've disabled all footers and such for what I think are the likely culprits. When opening the page (www.communionchapelefca.org/edy-home) it does not display the white block at the bottom.

Let me know if I need to post any other XML or java files. Thanks for your help.

Comment: post your xml and the related java code

Comment: Are you sure the padding is from your layout/application and not the website/HTML itself? Might want to include the URL/HTML you are loading as well.

Comment: added the XML and java files.

concerning the html portion, we use wordpress to host our site and ive disabled all the portions for the page that add the footer. you can view the link here www.communionchapelefca.org/edy-home

Comment: Anyone have a clue what Im doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Well all I did to fix it was hit the enter key about five times (to add space between the last text within the document). Then I added text to the bottom of my html document and then colored that text the same color as the background. Not a pretty fix but it worked.